# Difference between entity type and entity set?

Tags: database

What is attribute. What is the difference between entity, entity type and entity set? Please explain the difference with an example.

Answer (score 37):

### STUDENT

### ID   Name  AGE

1    Ram   12
   2    Sam   13

Above is an example of a table called Student having 2 rows (1,Ram,12) and (2,Sam,13)   . Using this we can understand the difference.

### Entity

It is something which has real existence. Like tuple1 contains information about Ram(id, name and Age) which has existence in real world . So the tuple1 is an entity. So we may say **each tuple is an entity**.

### Entity Type

It is collection of entity having common attribute. As in Student table each row is an entity and have common attributes. So **STUDENT** is an entity type which contains entities having attributes id, name and Age.Also each entity type in a database is described by a name and a list of attribute.So we may say **a table is an entity type**

### Entity SET

It is a set of entities of same entity type. so a set of one or more entities of Student Entity type is an Entity Set.

### ATTRIBUTE

It is a property of an entity. For example, in table STUDENT id,name and Age are properties of an entity of entity type student. Hence these are attributes.

Comments are Welcome

Comment: How about the entity instance ?

Comment: @BillyHalim entity and entity instance both are same

Comment: "A table is an entity type" This is misleading. The table name specifies the table's entity type. However, the table itself is an entity set.

Answer (score 3):

Entity means anything with distinct and independent existence.
Entity type is basically a collection of entities that have the similar attributes.
Entity set is the collection as a set of all entities of the similar type.
So, Entity type and entity set are analogous.
Example of entity set: set of all persons, universities, companies
An entity is represented by a set of attributes, that is descriptive properties possessed by all members of an entity set.
Example: student = (student-id, student-name, address-street, address-city), item = (item-number, price)

Answer (score 0):

The entity type refers to the collection of entity that share a common definition
Entity set is the set of entities of the same type that share the same attributes.Eg set of all people who are customer at a particular bank can be defined as the entity customer.

Answer (score 0):

Entity type is a group of entities that has similar attributes. 
While, 
Entity set of entities of the same entity type.