# What's the difference between entity, entity type, and entity instance?

Tags: database

I need help to differentiate the terminology between an entity, entity instance and entity type, My lecturer uses a slide based on this 
[site](http://www.siue.edu/~dbock/cmis450/3-ermodel.htm), and seems to have mixed up the uses of the word, when she refers to an ER diagram she always say ex: EMPLOYEE as an entity, but from the definition isn't it an entity type? thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to look for more sources. E.g. wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model

Comment: "Because the term entity-type is somewhat cumbersome, most people tend to use the term entity as a synonym for this term" 

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I suppose it's better to ask such questions on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com) than on StackOverflow

Answer (score 2):

In definition:

**Entity:**  Entity is a **concept to abstractly** represent all instances of a group of similar “things”.

**Entity Type:**  It is **collection of entity** having common attribute.

**Entity Instance:** An entity instance is a **single occurrence of an entity**.

So to clarify your confusion, **entity** is a more abstract or general way of referring to an entity instance or a type.And yes EMPLOYEE is an entity type.

References:[instance](https://gerardnico.com/data/modeling/instance),[entity](https://gerardnico.com/data/modeling/entity),[another answer with example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26653114/difference-between-entity-type-and-entity-set)

Answer (score 0):

Entity: An entity can be a real-world object, either animate or inanimate, that can be easily identifiable.

Entity type: An entity type is a collection of similar entities.

Entity instance: A member of entity type